# Laravel Forge site working everywhere but Chrome on laptop

Tags: google-chrome, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-forge

I have launched a site using Laravel Forge/Digital Ocean, and the website works fine in:

Safari Browser (mobile and laptop)
Google Chrome Browser (only on mobile)

but it is not working in the Google Chrome Browser on my laptop (which is weird, if it works in the chrome mobile browser).

This is the error I get when I try to access it on my laptop with Chrome:

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

The server at www.mywebpage.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.
```

I know the nameservers are set up correctly, and I have the two A fields set up under my namerecords:

```
mywebpage.com    A
*.mywebpage.com  A
```

What is going on with Chrome and my site?

Comment: So, it looks like http://mywebpage.com works.  But typing "www.mywebpage.com" into the browsers does not work.

Comment: You need to add the `"www.mywebpage.com"` in to your DO account.

Comment: `"www.mywebpage.com"` is different than `"mywebpage.com"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to your Digital Ocean,

Networking > Domains > add `www.mywebpage.com` > Create Record

[image]

Then, you should be able to go to it. Like mine : [www.bunlongheng.com](http://www.bunlongheng.com/)